# MARS Mips Adding more than 2 registers/printing solution

Tags: assembly, integer, mips, addition

I did a few calculations (not even sure if they're remotely close to accurate as the instructions for the assignment are non existent (thanks worthless professors)) but basically I'm trying to take the value of $t2, $t3, $t4, and $t5.. add them together, then store them in $t6 and print that to the console.

Heres what I have so far

```
    li $v0,10
    li $t1, 10
    add $t2, $t1, $t1
    sll $t3, $t1, 2
    and $t4, $t1, 0x0000FFFF
    or $t5, $t1, 0x0000FFFF
```

Comment: If all you want to do is add, what's up with the shift, and the bitwise ops? Also `$t6` isn't even mentioned.

Comment: I haven't ever used an assembly language, not sure what that means.  The instructions ask for us to do bitwise and and bitwise or operations. Why? No idea.  Theoretically, $t6 would be add $t6, $t2....... etc etc but obviously I can't add more than 2 registers hence the question of what do I do

Comment: You said you wanted to add those. That's all we can work with. If you have other constraints, [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60268548/edit). In any case, your code is wrong. As you said, you can only add two registers at once. So calculate as `(($t2+$t3)+$t4)+$t5`. That's 3 additions. Has little to do with assembly, it's basic maths.

Comment: `add $t1, $t2, $t3` `add $t2, $t4, $t5` `add $t1, $t2, $t1` after this $t1 should have the summ. Also take a look at this https://godbolt.org/z/a96NLJ. Might give you ideas.

Comment: So back to the question, I can't add two registers.  How should I structure it to add all of these values?  Do I add a couple registers at a time, store them in new variables and then add later?  That's the entirety of the question.  How do I structure this?  Again, haven't used assembly so not sure what to do.

Comment: You can't add two registers? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

```
    .data ## Data declaration section
    .text ## Assembly language instructions go in text segment
main: ## Start of code section
    add $t1, $t2, $t3 # t1 = t2 + t3
    add $t2, $t4, $t5 # t2 = t4 + t5
    add $t6, $t2, $t1 # t6 = t1 + t2
    move $a0, $t6 # a0 = t6
    li $v0, 1 # system call code to print integer from a0
    syscall # call operating system to perform operation
    li $v0, 10 # terminate program
    syscall
```

Found the example Hello World! program here: https://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2506/Fall2014/Notes/L04.MIPSAssemblyOverview.pdf

Which I extended according to your requirements.

This code will output 0 if you run it on MARS simulator, since t2, t3, t4, t5 are 0 basically.